# Using the :not CSS selector

Tags: html, css

I want to color all my `p` in blue, except the one inside the no-color div.

I tried `p:not(.no-color)`, `:not(.no-color) p`, `div:not(.no-color) p` but I think I misunderstand something

```css
p:not(.no-color) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <div class="no-color"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <div class="random-class"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
</div>
```

Edit: The HTML code is retrieved automatically, so I can't choose on which elements I apply the classes. I can only stylize in CSS.

Comment: Can't do that with CSS only, as it would take a _parent selector_, which doesn't exists (yet)

Comment: You can try this https://jsfiddle.net/0zLonhjc/ `.no-color p {..}` `p{..}`

Comment: "." before an item specifies a css class for **that object**, try `.no-color p{color: blue}`

Comment: If the parent element is known, e.g. they all where a child of the `body`, this would work though: `body > p {
  color: blue;
}`

Comment: @LGSon I don't understand what you mean by parent selector ? I edited my code, is that possible now ?

Comment: Yes, with that change you can do `.container > p
{
  color: blue;
}`. This say "change all `p` that is a child of the `container`"

Comment: Hum yes but it does not solve my problem actually^^, I edited the code again, and in this case it doesn't work the way I would like

Comment: @Vald I updated Yann39's answer to cover that as well

Comment: @Vald What I meant with a _parent selector_ is that one can't say _"color all `p` if the `p`'s parent is not an element with class `.no-color`"_

Comment: There is a workaround on this but currently it's not well support. Read more here: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this if you can't modify the HTML :

```css
.container > p,
.container > div:not(.no-color) > p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <div class="no-color">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <div class="random-class">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I know, the problem is that I have stylized blockquote (with more than 20 CSS lines), so I have to cancel the 20 CSS properties for the no-color class. I was wondering if there was an easier way with the :not selector

Comment: Unfortunaltely as stated by @LGSon this is not possible if you don't apply it from a known parent (I used `body` here but you can use a closer one of course), because there is no parent selector in CSS.

Comment: @Yann39 Now you can edit your answer, as OP added some more code that will work with your logic.

Comment: @LGSon Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This selector should work, without modifying the HTML:

```css
:not(.no-color) > p {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <div class="no-color"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <div class="random-class"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
</div>
```

(Sorry for my previous, unhelpful answers... I actually tested this one!)

EDIT: Fixed answer

Comment: The markup can't be changed, which make this answer wrong.

Comment: Please see my edited answer, with an additional solution.

Comment: Always try what you suggest before posting it, and if you would, you would see this won't work

Comment: @LGSon You are absolutely right! I did test this latest edit.

Comment: This indeed works with new OP requirement, but note that this will not work if you have other enclosing elements arround your `p` (i.e. `<div class="no-color"><div><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div></div>`)

Answer (score 0):

I would place the class on the `<p>` instead, then `p:not(.no-color)` would work.

If however, you can't change the HTML structure, you can target `<p>`s which are descendants of an element with a `.no-color` class by using the `.no-color p` selector and then set the color to `inherit`.

Setting the color to `inherit` allows you to get the color of the enclosing parent without specifying it.

This technique works for arbitrarily nested `<p>` elements below a `.no-color` parent.

```css
p {
  color: blue;
}
.no-color p {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<div class="no-color">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<div class="no-color">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```